# Slack api returns `is_bot`: False for a bot. How else to check if an user is bot?

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

`slackbot` might be dear to slack, but still he's a bot isn't he?

using [python-slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) I did. `slack_client.api_call("users.list")`

`users = self.slack_client.api_call("users.list")
    for member in users["members"]:
        print(member)`

Prints this for `slackbot`:

`{'is_owner': False, 'tz_offset': -28800, 'is_ultra_restricted': False, 'tz': None, 'profile': {'image_48': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/2fac/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_48.png', 'image_192': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/slackbot_192.png', 'avatar_hash': 'sv1444671949', 'fields': None, 'image_32': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/2fac/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_32.png', 'image_512': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/1801/img/slackbot_512.png', 'image_72': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_72.png', 'image_24': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_24.png', 'real_name': 'slackbot', 'first_name': 'slackbot', 'last_name': '', 'real_name_normalized': 'slackbot'}, 'status': None, 'team_id': 'T2YJG4LLV', 'name': 'slackbot', 'tz_label': 'Pacific Standard Time', 'is_restricted': False, 'id': 'USLACKBOT', 'color': '757575', 'is_bot': False, 'is_primary_owner': False, 'is_admin': False, 'deleted': False, 'real_name': 'slackbot'}`

Notice, `'is_bot': False`. How do I reliably check if a user is a bot. I used to check if the user profile information had `email` field in it, will that do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that `is_bot` will be `false` for the Slackbot. However `is_bot` will be `true` for other bots.

Just identify the Slackbot by its ID, witch is always `USLACKBOT` and the rest of the bots with `is_bot`.

Comment: cool! I was thinking that might be a case. Thanks for clarifying :)